# Global Optimization: How to find same minimum more consistently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy

Currently I am using basinhopping from scipy library to find the optimal x (where x consists out of 4 factors total) that is optimizing my objective function. When I let it run several times it will give me different results for each run. Is there a way to make the result more consistent (i.e. function's minimizing parameters same over several iterations)?

```
cons = [
    {
        'type': 'eq',
        'fun': lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 1
    },
    {
        'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda x: (w_0 / prob_death(T)[T-1]) - x[3]
    },
    {
        'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda x: x[3] - 10000
     }
]

bounds = ( (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1'000'000)) )

res = basinhopping(func = utility_expected,
          x0 = np.array([0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 50000]),
          minimizer_kwargs = {"method": 'SLSQP',
          "bounds": bounds,
          "constraints": cons,
          "options": {
              "eps": 0.01,
              "ftol": 0.001
              }
          }, 
          disp = False,
          interval = 40,
          niter = 250)
```

Comment: This feels like an extremely broad optimization question; probably should belong to math.SE but it might turn out too broad even there.

Comment: basinhopping is a randomized algorithm. You can set the seed to make runs reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not familiar with scipy's basinhopping in particular, but if I'm reading this right, you've given it a epsilon of 0.01 for numerical approximation of the Jacobian.  However, your variables are scaled very differently. (0-1 versus 0-1000000)  That's likely to give you weird behavior.  Consider scaling your fourth variable into 0-1.

Also, 250 iterations is a really tiny number for what you're asking the optimizer to do.  Try making it run longer.